# Does NEAR need both Serialize and BorshSerialize?

Tags: serialization, rust, nearprotocol

Writing NEAR smart contracts in Rust, my compiler seems to require objects sent through the API to have the `Serialize` trait, and objects stored in the blockchain to have `BorshSerialize` and `BorshDeserialize`.  Is that really the case, or am I doing something wrong?  I would have thought that `BorshSerialize` would provide `Serialize`, and that you could use one library for both purposes.

Answer (score 4):

> I would have thought that BorshSerialize would provide Serialize

That is not the case. `BorshSerialize` is specific to [Borsh](https://borsh.io/) whereas `Serialize` comes from [serde](https://serde.rs/) and neither implies the other. The reason why return type requires `Serialize` is because we want it to be serialized as json so that it is easy to handle on the frontend.

Comment: To clarify, the reason why Borsh does not implement serde Serialize, is because that would impede its performance and significantly increase the code size, which affects the size of the compiled contract.

Answer (score 4):

Your observation is correct. `Serialize` is serde::Serialize, with serde_json gives you serde Serialize. `BorshSerailize` is serialize with [borsh](https://borsh.io), commonly used serialization format implemented by NEAR to store data on chain. Depending on your use case you might want to use them both or separately. Separately: you create "model" that store on chain that has only `BorshSerialize`, create "view" that returns by API that has only `Serialize`.